# Default Activity not found .I see many solution but does not work for me

Tags: android, android-studio

Default Activity not found. I faced this problem from last 4 days. I tried all possible solution on stack over flow. but nothing work ..! only one solution is working almost 1 time only if I click on sync project with Gradle Files. some times its work or some time its not.

> Edit Configuration

[image]

> MainActivity.Xml

[image]

> MainActivity.java

[image]

> but I select Nothing option in Launch it work ..but no any activity launch in the physical device

[image]

> Android Manifest

[image]

> build.gradle

[image]

Comment: in `MainActivity.xml` under `tools.context` the `.MainActivity` is red. What is the package structure in `app.src.main.java` ?

Comment: where I can find this package structure..? Sorry I dont know where it is

Comment: like [this](https://cdn.journaldev.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/android-project-view.png) on left side

Comment: and you say, that it sometimes works. have you tried to clean up the project from old `gradle` packages, updated your Android Studio?

Comment: I cant update my android studio ..its only work if I click on sync project with gradle file option

Comment: what version of android studio do you have?

Comment: Android studio 3.4.1

Comment: `Android studio 3.4.1` don't support API 29. You should update `Android Studio` (or make new installation) or downgrade API

Comment: but bro it work fine on android 3.4.1 .. and suddenly this happen

Comment: Have you tried inavlidating caches/restart from the file menu? Also, have you tried clicking clean project and then rebuild project from build menu? You can also try deleting `.gradle` folder from root directory of your project (it's completely safe) and then rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as said [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/setup-sdk)

*The Android 10 SDK includes changes that are **not compatible with some older versions** of Android Studio. So, for the best development experience, we **recommend that you install the latest version** of Android Studio.
You can compile and test Android 10 apps using Android Studio 3.3 and higher, but some users of the Android 10 SDK may encounter Gradle **sync failures** and warnings about outdated dependencies.*

It is recommended to use `Android Studio 4` with `SDK 29`

Comment: now I understand.but I have concern about updates ..becuse my final project is on 29 june .. if after updates some thing is happen ..I mean new updates  is safe for my code or UI .. ?/

Comment: You can leave your current `Android Studio` version on PC. In some other folder download the new version and start from there. You can also save your current project as archive, for case if something goes wrong. But there should be no problem.